# Parameters with rails link_to new_path remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to-remote

I have an object `title` with an association `song`

In my index of a titles, each `title` has a `link_to` button that creates a new `title` that I would like associated with the same `song` object. So it's something like this:

```
link_to "Add Title", new_title_path, remote: true
```

In the view that has the above code I have the `song_id`. I can display the form that gets returned when this link is clicked, I can submit the data and create the new `title` but how do I get the `song_id` into that form or into the new `title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter to the link, assuming `song` is the object

```
link_to "Add Title", new_title_path(song_id: @title.song_id), remote: true
```

Now in the new action

```
def new
  @title = Title.new(song_id: params[:song_id])
end
```

and finally in the `new.html.erb` form, add a hidden field tag

```
<%= f.hidden_field :song_id, @title.song_id %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is that GET request the "rails way"?

Comment: okay, I figured out how to do it the rails way - I'll edit your answer